# Javascript new with hard binding

Tags: javascript, this

I have the following code snippet

```js
function foo(a) {
    this.a = a;
}

var obj = {a: 77};

var bar = function() {
    return foo.apply( obj, arguments );
};

var o = new bar( 2 );

console.log( o.a ); // I think it's 2(why is it undefined?)
console.log(obj.a); // obj.a changed to 2, got it.
```

Why is `o.a` undefined? also if I delete the `return` keyword in `bar`, it will still be the same.

```js
function foo(a) {
    this.a = a;
}

var obj = {a: 77};

var bar = function() {
    foo.apply( obj, arguments );
};

var o = new bar( 2 );

console.log( o.a ); // I think it's 2(why is it undefined?)
console.log(obj.a); // obj.a changed to 2, got it.
```

The question is actually what happens when hard binding and new binding happens the same time

Comment: Maybe `return new foo.apply(obj, arguments);` and `var o = bar(2);` instead of `var o = new bar(2);`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. You never make use of `this` within `bar`, so why would `o` have any data set?

Comment: `return new (foo.bind.apply(foo, [null].concat([].slice.call(arguments)))); var o = bar(2)`. You can do this more easily in ES6.

Comment: I can't determine what you are actually trying to accomplish here. Do you actually want to change `obj` in `foo` or just use `obj` to set `this.a`?

Comment: I am not trying to accomplish anything but to understand how `this` is affected

Answer (score 1):

Using [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) will create a new object and assign that object as `this` to the function you call it on. In your case, you're not using the new object and instead are calling a function setting `obj` as `this`.

As to why adding and removing `return` doesn't change anything is because in both cases, you're returning `undefined`. When a function is called with `new` and returns `undefined` (a.k.a the default return value) it returns the new object generated by `new`.

To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description):

> The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

So you create a new object but manipulate an old object. Your code effectively works like this.

```js
function foo(a) {
    this.a = a;
}

var obj = {a: 77};

var bar = function() {
    return foo.apply( obj, arguments );
};

var o = {}; // Originally you used `new` to create a new object
bar(2); // Since `bar` doesn't use `this`, it's the same as if it were called by itself

console.log(o.a); // Empty object
console.log(obj.a); // Modified by `bar`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return `this` from `foo(a)`, like so:

```js
function foo(a) {
    this.a = a;
    // "this" NEEDS TO BE RETURNED, OTHERWISE (bar)'s 
    // VALUE WILL BE UNDEFINED, THUS o.a WILL BE UNDEFINED
    return this; 
}

var obj = {a: 77};

var bar = function() {
    // MAKE SURE THIS IS RETURNED AS WELL
    return foo.apply( obj, arguments );
};

var o = new bar( 2 );

console.log( o.a ); // I think it's 2(why is it undefined?)
console.log(obj.a); // obj.a changed to 2, got it.
```

> The question is actually what happens when hard binding and new
>   binding happens the same time

In this case nothing because  a new instance of `new bar( 2 )` is useless when its return value is dependent on `foo(a)`, and `foo(a)` is dependent on a singleton (`obj`).

I hope that helps!